# HPGL from LaTeX / TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, inkscape, pgflayers

I want to generate HPGL code for my HP pen plotter from my TikZ figures. Has anyone ever done something similar?
My current approach is to import the pdf into Inkscape and let Inkscape generate the HPGL file. To plot different colors and line widths, different pens / layers are needed. Inkscape imports the whole figure as one layer.

Is there a way to generate different layers for the grid, axis, different plots, etc. in TikZ, which then can be easily overlayed in Inkscape?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!